# angularjs open new link in the same partialview?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement an "open link from partial view controller in new tab" function using

```
 var win = window.open(result.signatureClientUrl, '_top'); 
 win.focus();
```

or

```
var win = window.open(result.signatureClientUrl, '_top');
```

However, the link is replacing the parent tab but what I want it really is that link open in the same partial view not in the main page, not in the new tab 
is there is any trick to open the link in the same partial view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***window.location.href*** instead of window.open() .
like: window.location.href = "http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html";